# Visual Studio Code output window stays empty using scriptcsRunner

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, scriptcs

I've been trying to fiddle around with Scriptcs and since I don't always want to fire up Visual Studio and use the interactive window, I'd tried my hand with Visual Studio code.

These are the steps I've taken:

1. `@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scriptcs-contrib/svm/master/install/installer.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%HOME%\.svm\bin\;%HOME%\.svm\shims\;%PATH%`
2. `svm install 0.15.0`
3. VS Code -> `ext install scriptcsRunner` -> Restart VS Code

Using a command prompt and issuing `scriptcs [enter] Console.WriteLine("foo"); [enter]` returns `foo`.

Using sublime Text 3, I get the same results. However, in Visual Studio code executing it with `Ctrl + Shift + R` gives me an empty Output window. How can I debug and rectify this?

Comment: That extension should have an author you can contact. Meanwhile if it is open source like other extensions, you might even debug the code on your own. I guess it is a feature not yet implemented.